# <style> tag code not deploying in Firebase

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-hosting

I recently built an application using a Vue/Vuetify frontend and Firebase that involved importing some CSS files (Materialize) as well as some custom style scripts on the vue files themselves (encapsulated by  tags).

After running "npm run build" and deploying, for some reason everything is fine (including any Javascript on the Vue pages) except for that any styling I did in the style tags does not show up.

Does anyone know why this is? Does it have to do with using Vue? I'm confused since the Materialize styling still works. I hope this question is clear, thank you!

Comment: I think problem is in your bundler(webpack or something) config

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? I am using webpack to do the bundling. How can I check if it's doing it properly?

Comment: did you create your project from vue-cli or from some vue-webpack-template? or you fill webpack config by yourself?

Comment: I created the project through vue-cli so it generated the webpack.prod.conf.js file.